# sending '+' character utf-8, java App to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to write a byte buffer which contains this kind of strings
   *&field_Value=*

```
kggsW9YizUuRpjB/RtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw+wPMwn7fWJva0QbSK/Slt/DDsZ
```

through a HttpURLConnection, but I receive *&field_Value=*

```
kggsW9YizUuRpjB/RtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw wPMwn7fWJva0QbSK/Slt/DDsZ
```

So '+' is the only character which is not send. It happens with all my strings that contain a '+' inside.

Could you tell me how to encode the strings or what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

Sender:

```
url = new URL(url_globalApp);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); 
        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        //**************** first try ************//
        wr.write(pairs_1.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, pairs_1.length());

        //**************** second try ************//
            //wr.writeBytes(new String(pairs_1.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));

        //**************** third try ************//
            //wr.writeUTF(pairs_1);
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    Map <String,String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
    System.out.println(parameters.get("field_value_1")[0]);
```

Comment: URLEncode the `+`; which is an encoding for `' '`.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that. Do I have to become the ' ' into '+'? Is there another solution? I'll receive a lot of info in this servlet.

Comment: You can use `URLEncoder.encode(String)` to encode the entire `String`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the right way to encode but when I try to get the parameter Map it doesn't work. At least the string it's ok in the server side.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2793150

Comment: Thanks @BalusC I was using `URLEncoder.encode()` with the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a query parameter *must* be URL encoded.

The URL encoding of

```
kggsW9YizUuRpjB/RtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw+wPMwn7fWJva0QbSK/Slt/DDsZ
```

is

```
kggsW9YizUuRpjB%2FRtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw%2BwPMwn7fWJva0QbSK%2FSlt%2FDDsZ
```

Notice how `/` is encoded to `%2F`, and `+` is encoded to `%2B`.

You do it by calling

```java
java.net.URLEncoder.encode("kggsW9YizUuRpjB/RtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw+wPMwn7fWJva0QbSK/Slt/DDsZ", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the right way to encode but when I try to get the parameter Map it doesn't work. At least the string it's ok on the server side. Do you have a solution to get the parameter Map?

Comment: @SergioBaquero What does "doesn't work" mean? Is the map empty? What is value of `request.getQueryString()`?

Comment: Yes, when I run `parameters.containsKey("field_"+String.valueOf(i))` it returns false, just when the request is encoded.

Comment: @SergioBaquero Can't help if you don't answer my actual questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see, give me a second please

Comment: Sorry @Andreas it took me some time to say the answer is `null`

Comment: @SergioBaquero There is your answer. If `getQueryString()` is null, then no query parameters were given, so of course `getParameterMap()` is empty.

Comment: But it just happens when it's encoded. Look at this please. some words are in spanish: 

`null
valor started
valor 2
valor Y3PT8kLdNLbncqH10v5iS6YK3LTkAbX51xfCw4b5hFNrxUUQp/5AkURZ3a2thFFM
valor 5
valor 2016-03-10
valor 1`

this is the output which measn `getQueryString()` is empty but info is there.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at. I don't see any `&field_Value=kggsW9YizUuRpjB%2FRtppZImnC8SekMGAWGnCmw%2BwPMwn7fWJva0QbSK%2FSlt%2FDDsZ`

Comment: You're right. The `getQueryString()` return null both cases when info is encoded or not. But the parameter Map is empty just when info is encoded.

Comment: What is value of `pairs_1`? What is value of `getParameterMap()`? with and without encoding, for both. Edit question, show MCVE. I'm off, night.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I was using `URLEncoder.encode()` with the entire query. Now I see my question was written wrong.